# Store index from array in matrix

Tags: matrix

Hi I want to store a matrix of `[480][320]` elements to convert it to coordinates of real world.
I need to save the elements and to be display in a `.txt` like this: `[numRow][numCol][depth]`.

I'm using C++

```
 for(int y=0; y<depthMap.rows; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<depthMap.cols; x++)
        {
            dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
            file << x << " " << y << " " << dist << endl; 
        }
    }
```

I want to store as a matrix to put as an input in the next method and that way to convert into XYZ but not only for one value as if I do like this but for all the values

```
Vec3f depthToXYZ(int x, int y, int depthValue)
```

Comment: Could you please show some of the code that you've tried. I'm unclear on what you mean by the fact that you "want to store a matrix of [480][320] elements to convert it to coordinates of real world"

Comment: I edited my question with the code i'm using